# backgroung-image url is executing before controller complete request?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I'm learning Angular JS now.

Now I need to show an article in the page, and the article data is getting from the backend in controller.js.

But I found there will be 2 requests to get the article background image. One is wrong, and the other is right.

[image]

[image]

It seems the background-image: url executes before controller set the value for {{}}.

**Could anyone give me some suggestions to avoid the wrong request?**

Here is code below.

```
<header class="intro-header" style="background-image: url('{{ article_data.article_title_pic }}')">
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-lg-8 col-lg-offset-2 col-md-10 col-md-offset-1">
            <div class="post-heading">
                <h1>{{ article_data.article_title }}</h1>
                <!--<h2 class="subheading">Problems look mighty small from 150 miles up</h2>-->
                <span class="meta">Posted by <a href="#">{{ article_data.article_author }}</a> on {{ article_data.article_time | formatDate}}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

controller.js

```
    // controller
myControllers.controller('articleContrl', ['$scope', 'RestServer', '$routeParams', function ($scope, RestServer, $routeParams) {
    // data
    $scope.article_data = {};

    // article id
    $scope.article_id = $routeParams.id;
    //console.log("$scope.article_id: " + $scope.article_id);

    // get article data from server
    var get_article = function (article_id) {
        RestServer.post(
            "/get_article",
            {
                "article_id": article_id
            },
            function (response) {
                if (response.result === "success") {
                    // success
                    $scope.article_data = response.data;
                }
                else {
                    console.log("get_article fail, error: " + response.error);
                    $scope.errorMessage = response.error;
                }
            },
            function (err) {
                // failed
                console.log("get_article fail, error: " + err);
                $scope.errorMessage = err;
            }
        );
    };

    // main
    get_article($scope.article_id);
}]);
```

Thanks.

Comment: Thanks @ConvertToInt32. Because ng-src can not use in background-image. I change it to ng-style. It can also fix my problem.

Comment: ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')'}"

Answer (score 0):

use the Angular JS directive to solve this problem. Like ng-style="{'background-image': 'url(' + selectedMeal.url + ')'}".